# Python3 - Convert a string to dict

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this string which I wish to convert to a dict:

```
class_="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535"
```

to basically change it to something like:

```
dict(class_='template_title', height='50', valign='bottom', width='535')
```

Nothing more complicated but I believe there is multiple steps in this problem. Would be nice if you could explain the solution or link to some documentation  :)

Comment: Hello @bob could you check other answer might be help you. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a dictionary object from that string, you can use the `dict` function and a generator expression which splits the string based on whitespaces and then by `=`, like this

```
>>> data = 'class_="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535"'
>>> dict(item.split('=') for item in data.split())
{'width': '"535"', 'height': '"50"', 'valign': '"bottom"', 'class_': '"template_title"'}
```

This follows from the examples in [this documentation section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). So, if you pass an iterable which gives two elements on every iteration, then `dict` can use that to create a dictionary object.

In this case, we first split the string based on whitespace characters with `data.split()` and then we split every string based on `=`, so that we will get key, value pairs.

**Note:** If you are sure that the data will not have `"` character anywhere inside the string, then you can replace that first and then do the dictionary creation operation, like this

```
>>> dict(item.split('=') for item in data.replace('"', '').split())
{'width': '535', 'height': '50', 'valign': 'bottom', 'class_': 'template_title'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python 3, so this may not be the most elegant solution, but this approach would work.

First split the string by spaces. `list_of_records = string.split()`

This returns a list that in your case would look like this:

`['class_="template_title"', 'height="50"', 'valign="bottom"', 'width="535"']`

Then iterate through the list and split each element by '='.

```
for pair in list_of_records:
    key_val = pair.split('=')
    key = pair[0]
    val = pair[1]
```

Now in the body of the loop, just add it to the dictionary.

```
d[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you *don't* have the variables defined as a string. You just have variables.

You can look into the following functions,

- dir() will give you the list of in scope variables:
- globals() will give you a dictionary of global variables
- locals() will give you a dictionary of local variables

These will give you the dictionary which you can manipulate, filter, all sort of things.

Something like this,

```
class_m="template_title" 
height_m="50" 
valign_m="bottom" 
width_m="535"

allVars = locals()
myVars = {}
for key,val in allVars.items():
    if key.endswith('_m'):
        myVars[key] = val

print(myVars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this way, View [**LIVE**](http://ideone.com/bkcEol)

```
ori = 'class_="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535"'
final = dict()
for item in ori.split():
    pair = item.split('=')
    final.update({pair[0]: pair[1][1:-1]})
print (final)
```

Output:

```
{'class_': 'template_title', 'valign': 'bottom', 'width': '535', 'height': '50'}
```